# Adding vectors intuition.

Tags: vectors

Say an object is traveling at $3m/s$ east and $4m/s$ north we know that it's traveling at $5m/s$ north east. Question is why can we justify treating  velocities as we treat distances. Let $x$ be horizontal  displacement, $y$ be vertical, and $z$ be the actual (north east) displacement.

If:

1)

$$x^2+y^2=z^2$$

2)

$$2x(\frac{dx}{dt})+2y(\frac{dy}{dt})=2z(\frac{dz}{dt})$$

Than how can we conclude:

$$(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2=(\frac{dz}{dt})^2$$

To justify what we are doing.

Comment: Nice proof. Since you answered your own question, you *could* have posted anything after the first paragraph as an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry what did I prove? I'm confused.

Comment: I'm trying to see how to go from 2) to the conclusion. Is multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{2t}$ and saying $\frac{dx}{dt}={x}{t}$ for a constant $\frac{dx}{dt}$ enough? @AdamHrankowski

Comment: Then again: This is wrong relativistically